# O programa não retorna para o menu após a chamada da funcao em C

Tags: c

Criei 2 funções, uma função menu e outra `incluirRegistroDeObras` que pode ser ativada pelo menu. Entretanto. Ao ativar a opcao do `incluirRegistroDeObras`, eu consigo executar a função, mas ao final dela o programa fecha e nao retorna para o menu.

Ja tentei a solucao proposta na pergunta [Como retornar ao menu apos executar função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128567/como-retornar-ao-menu-apos-executar-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o), mas nao funcionou.

Segue o enunciado do problema e o código abaixo:

> José, professor universitário de Arquitetura e Urbanismo, possui em seu escritório caixas e mais caixas de livros e revistas, que aos poucos estão sendo catalogados por sua secretária Vanessa. Vanessa está catalogando em uma planilha eletrônica os principais dados de Livros e Revistas, tais como (título da obra, edição, nome do autor, editora, isbn, quantidade de exemplares, caixa onde a obra está armazenada e ano).
>
> A proposta da atividade mapa, é o desenvolvimento de um sistema de    pequeno porte para o controlar onde estão armazenadas as obras do arquiteto. Para a construção deste sistema, você deverá utilizar a linguagem C, armazenando os dados em arquivo texto.
>
> O sistema a ser construído necessitará atender aos requisitos funcionais abaixo:
>
> 1. Possuir a sua identificação (RA-Nome-Curso)
> 2. Possuir um menu de opção.
>
>    2.1. Incluir o registro das obras.
>
>    2.2. Listar todos os livros.
>
>    2.3. Listar todas as revistas.
>
>    2.4. Listar as obras por caixa.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// constantes com os dados do aluno
#define nome "Alexandre Guerreiro";
#define RA "19110675-5";


//Prototipacao (definicao do prototipo das funcoes que serao utilizadas)
//O sistema a ser construído necessitará atender aos requisitos funcionais abaixo:
//
//1 - Possuir a sua identificação (RA-Nome-Curso)
//2 - Possuir um menu de opção.
//2.1 - Incluir o registro das obras.
//2.2 - Listar todos os livros.
//2.3 - Listar todas as revistas.
//2.4- Listar as obras por caixa.

void menuOpcao();
void incluirRegistroDeObras();
void listarLivros();
void listarRevistas();
void listasObrasPorCaixa();

int main() {

    menuOpcao();

}


// estrutura obra(para livro e revistas). Deve conter:
// título da obra, edição, nome do autor, editora, isbn, quantidade de exemplares, caixa onde a obra está armazenada e ano.
typedef struct obra {
    int tipo; //aqui sera definido se a obra é um livro ou revista
    char autor[500];
    char titulo[500];
    char editora[500];
    int edicao;
    int isbn;
    int qtdExemplares;
    int anoLancamento;
    struct obra *anterior;
    struct obra *seguinte;
} obra;

obra *obras;

// estrutura da caixa onde sera armazenado os livros e revistas
typedef struct caixa {
    int capacidade;
    int qtdObrasArmazenadas;
    obra *inicio;
    obra *fim;
} caixa;

caixa *caixa1;
caixa *caixa2;
caixa *caixa3;

void incluirRegistroDeObras() {
    obra *novaObra;
    char getBuffer;
    novaObra = malloc(sizeof(obra));
    printf("\nRevista ou Livro? (1 para revista e 2 para livro): ");
    scanf("%d", &novaObra->tipo);
    scanf("%c", &getBuffer);
    printf("%d",novaObra->tipo);
    printf("\nTítulo da obra: ");
    fgets(novaObra->titulo,sizeof novaObra->titulo,stdin);
    printf("%s",novaObra->titulo);
    printf("\nAutor da obra: ");
    fgets(novaObra->autor,sizeof novaObra->autor,stdin);
    printf("%s",novaObra->autor);
    printf("\nEditora da obra: ");
    fgets(novaObra->editora,sizeof novaObra->editora,stdin);
    printf("%s",novaObra->editora);
    printf("\nNúmero da edicao da obra: ");
//    fgets(novaObra->edicao,sizeof novaObra->edicao,stdin);
    scanf("%d", &novaObra->edicao);
    scanf("%c", &getBuffer);
    printf("%d",novaObra->edicao);
    printf("\nNúmero ISBN: ");
//    fgets(novaObra->isbn,sizeof novaObra->isbn,stdin);
    scanf("%d", &novaObra->isbn);
    scanf("%c", &getBuffer);
    printf("%d",novaObra->isbn);
    printf("\nQuantidade de exemplares disponíveis: ");
//    fgets(novaObra->qtdExemplares,sizeof novaObra->qtdExemplares,stdin);
    scanf("%d", &novaObra->qtdExemplares);
    scanf("%c", &getBuffer);
    printf("%d",novaObra->qtdExemplares);
    printf("\nAno de lancamento: ");
//    fgets(novaObra->anoLancamento,sizeof novaObra->anoLancamento,stdin);
    scanf("%d", &novaObra->anoLancamento);
    scanf("%c", &getBuffer);
    printf("%d",novaObra->anoLancamento);
    if (caixa1->inicio == NULL) {
        caixa1->inicio = novaObra;
    } else {
        caixa1->fim->anterior = caixa1->fim;
        caixa1->fim = novaObra;
        caixa1->qtdObrasArmazenadas++;
    }

}

void listarLivros() {
    caixa *tmp = caixa1;
    if (caixa1->qtdObrasArmazenadas > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < caixa1->qtdObrasArmazenadas; i++) {
            printf("%c", tmp->inicio->titulo);
            tmp->inicio = tmp->inicio->seguinte;
        }
    }
}


void menuOpcao() {
    int opcao = 0;
    do {
        printf("1 - Incluir o registro das obras.\n");
        printf("2 - Listar todos os livros.\n");
        printf("3 - Listar todas as revistas.\n");
        printf("4 - Listar as obras por caixa.\n");
        printf("5 - Sair.\n");
        printf("Opcao: ");
        scanf("%d",&opcao);
        getchar();
        system("cls || clear");
        switch(opcao) {
        case 1:
            incluirRegistroDeObras();
            break;
        case 2:
            listarLivros();
            break;
        case 3:
//        listarRevistas();
            break;
        case 4:
//        listasObrasPorCaixa();
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("\nAté a proxima!");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nOpcão inválida!\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (opcao!=5);

}
```

Comment: Onde que vc está declarando caixa1? E qual a definição do tipo obra?

Comment: @OGRO2077 editei a pergunta colocando o enunciado do problema e o codigo completo pra ficar de melhor entendimento.

Comment: Realmente esse app não está finalizado, existem vários erros inclusive na variável malloc onde eu não estou conseguindo finalizar o mesmo, além desse há outros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu programa tem muitos problemas e a solução para sua pergunta requer um pouco mais que uma mudança pontual.
O programa não retorna ao menu principal pq vc não está gerenciando as estruturas de dados direito, e suas operações com os ponteiros estão erradas gerando uma falha de segmentação.
Analisando o seu código, é necessário reestruturar a base dos dados, definir quem é o dono das estruturas, criar rotinas de inicialização e destruição, reescrever o menu, rotinas de entrada, entre outros.

Quando se define uma estrutura de dados é essencial se pensar em relações de propriedade e em quem que vai gerenciar o tempo de vida dos ponteiros na alocação dinâmica. No seu código não existe separação entre nós e dados, as listas e os caixas são variáveis globais, enfim, está uma bagunça. Essa é a minha sugestão de como resolver esse problema:

```
// Definição do tipo Obra

#define MAX_CARACTERES 500

typedef enum tipo_obra
{
    LIVRO   = 1,
    REVISTA = 2
} tipo_obra;

typedef struct obra
{
    tipo_obra tipo;
    char autor[MAX_CARACTERES], titulo[MAX_CARACTERES], editora[MAX_CARACTERES];
    int edicao, isbn, qtdExemplares, anoLancamento;
} obra;


// Definição do tipo Lista de Obras
typedef struct no_obra
{
    struct obra    *dados_obra;
    struct no_obra *anterior;
    struct no_obra *seguinte;
} no_obra;

no_obra* adicionar_no(no_obra** lista, obra* dados)
{
    no_obra* novo_no = malloc(sizeof(no_obra));
    novo_no->dados_obra = dados;

    if(*lista == NULL)
    {
        //inserir primeiro item da lista
        novo_no->anterior = novo_no->seguinte = NULL;
        *lista = novo_no;
    }
    else
    {
        //buscar último nó da lista
        no_obra* ultimo_no = *lista;
        while(ultimo_no->seguinte != NULL)
            ultimo_no = ultimo_no->seguinte;

        //inserir nó no fim da lista
        novo_no->anterior = ultimo_no;
        novo_no->seguinte = NULL;
        ultimo_no->seguinte = novo_no;
    }

    //retorna o nó adicionado ao fim da lista
    return novo_no;
}
```

Não defini a rotina de destruição da lista pq só estou reorganizando o código que vc postou, mas será necessário que vc implemente essa função para que o seu programa fique completo:

```
//pseudo-código
void destruir_lista(no_obra** lista)
{
    para cada nó em lista {
        deletar dados_obra
        remover nó da lista
        deletar nó
    }
}
```

Cada caixa deve ser dono de sua própria lista de obras, gerenciando os ponteiros quando necessário. Mantive as variáveis "qtdObrasArmazenadas" e "fim" pq não sei se vc planeja utilizá-las no futuro, mas por enquanto a existência delas não é necessária.

```
typedef struct caixa
{
    int qtdObrasArmazenadas;
    struct no_obra *inicio;
    struct no_obra *fim;
} caixa;

void inicializar_caixa(caixa* c)
{
    c->inicio = c->fim = NULL;
    c->qtdObrasArmazenadas = 0;
}
void destruir_caixa(caixa* c)
{
    //implementar
}
void adicionar_obra(caixa* c, obra* nova_obra)
{
    c->fim = adicionar_no(&c->inicio, nova_obra);
    (c->qtdObrasArmazenadas)++;
}
```

Na função main você pode utilizar um vetor de caixas para não precisar criar uma variável para cada caixa. Através das funções de inicialização e destruição, seu programa garante que as estruturas estão prontas durante os menus e que ao final da execução não existe vazamento de memória.

```
#define NUM_CAIXAS 3

int main()
{
    struct caixa caixas[NUM_CAIXAS];
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_CAIXAS; ++i)
        inicializar_caixa(&caixas[i]);
        
    // menus
    
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_CAIXAS; ++i)
        destruir_caixa(&caixas[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Para os menus tenho essa sugestão de implementação para vc ter uma referência de como utilizar as estruturas de dados de forma modularizada. Existem maneiras diferentes de se fazer os menus e essa sugestão não é a única implementação certa.

```
int menuPrincipal() 
{
    printf( "\n### MENU PRINCIPAL ###\n"
            "1 - Incluir livro.\n"
            "2 - Incluir revista.\n"
            "3 - Listar todos os livros.\n"
            "4 - Listar todas as revistas.\n"
            "5 - Listar as obras por caixa.\n"
            "6 - Sair.\n"
            "Opcao: ");
    int opcao = 0;
    scanf("%d",&opcao);
    return opcao;
}
int menuSelecionaCaixa()
{
    int id = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        printf( "Qual o id do caixa? (entradas válidas de 1 a %d)\n>> ", NUM_CAIXAS);
        scanf("%d", &id);

        if(id < 1 || id > NUM_CAIXAS)
            printf("Erro! Id de caixa inválido.\n");
        else
        {
            id = id - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return id;
}

int main()
{
    //inicializar caixas

    int op = menuPrincipal();
    while(op != 6) 
    {
        switch(op)
        {
        case 1:
            registrarObra(&caixas[menuSelecionaCaixa()], LIVRO);
            break;
        case 2:
            registrarObra(&caixas[menuSelecionaCaixa()], REVISTA);
            break;
        case 3:
            listarLivros(&caixas[menuSelecionaCaixa()]);
            break;
        case 4:
            listarRevistas(&caixas[menuSelecionaCaixa()]);
            break;
        case 5:
            listarObras(&caixas[menuSelecionaCaixa()]);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Erro! Opcão inválida!\n");
            break;
        }

        op = menuPrincipal();
    }

    //destruir caixas
}
```

A implementação das tarefas específicas são definidas em funções livres que tem como parâmetro um ponteiro para uma instância de uma caixa.

```
void registrarObra(caixa* c, tipo_obra tipo) 
{
    if (tipo == LIVRO) 
        printf("### Incluir Livro ###\n\n");
    else if(tipo == REVISTA)
        printf("### Incluir Revista ###\n\n");
    else 
    {
        printf("Erro! Tipo de obra inválido\n\n");
        return;
    }

    obra *nova_obra = malloc(sizeof(obra));
    nova_obra->tipo = tipo;

    printf("Título da obra: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(nova_obra->titulo, MAX_CARACTERES, stdin);
    nova_obra->titulo[strcspn(nova_obra->titulo, "\r\n")] = 0;

    printf("Autor da obra: ");
    fgets(nova_obra->autor, MAX_CARACTERES, stdin);
    nova_obra->autor[strcspn(nova_obra->autor, "\r\n")] = 0;

    printf("Editora da obra: ");
    fgets(nova_obra->editora, MAX_CARACTERES, stdin);
    nova_obra->editora[strcspn(nova_obra->editora, "\r\n")] = 0;

    printf("Número da edição da obra: ");
    scanf("%d", &(nova_obra->edicao));

    printf("Número ISBN: ");
    scanf("%d", &(nova_obra->isbn));

    printf("Quantidade de exemplares disponíveis: ");
    scanf("%d", &(nova_obra->qtdExemplares));

    printf("Ano de lancamento: ");
    scanf("%d", &(nova_obra->anoLancamento));


    adicionar_obra(c, nova_obra);
    printf("Obra \"%s\" adicionada com sucesso!\n\n", nova_obra->titulo);
}

void listarLivros(caixa* c) 
{
    //implementação
}
void listarRevistas(caixa* c) 
{
    //implementação
}
void listarObras(caixa* c) 
{
    //implementação
}
```

Essa implementação modularizada ajuda a evitar gambiarras no código. A função registrarObra, por exemplo, não precisa saber que caixa usa uma lista encadeada ou gerenciar os ponteiros de caixa. A única responsabilidade de registrarObra é receber a entrada do usuário, criar a estrutura da obra, e repassar os dados para que caixa realize a inserção.
As próximas implementações devem seguir a mesma estratégia para que o código seja organizado e fique mais fácil de adicionar funcionalidades ao programa.

Disponibilizei o código dessa resposta no meu [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/aviana37/stackoverflow/src/master/pt/456981/main.c) para que vc possa ter como referência. O programa não está finalizado, tudo que eu fiz foi reorganizar o código que vc postou. Testei esse código com o compilador GCC 10.0.1 no Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Brilhou demais OGRO2077!! Muito obrigado!! lendo e relendo sua aula de C! Valeu!

Comment: A função adicionar obra estava errada. Acabei de corrigir aqui. Abraço!
https://bitbucket.org/aviana37/stackoverflow/commits/a36f5ff3711f53ff99a84d1db631f3e7c28b2956